# Attribute Access to HttpContext in AspNetCore Api Controller Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributes, authorization

How can I do something like this:

```
        [OfficeAuthorize(HttpContext.Request.etc)]
```

I'm guessing it's some sort of DependencyInjection, but I'm not sure where I would do that.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/390422/Quick-Overview-of-Csharp-Attribute-Programming

Comment: My Api has the officeId in the Url

/api/{officeId}/etc

I want to check if the user is in that office with my own custom authorization attribute.

Answer (score 3):

the context was available via the AuthorizationFilterContext in the OnAuthorizing function

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var body = context.HttpContext.Request.Body;
        //custom validation rule
    }
```

Comment: Note that `AuthorizationFilterContext` also has a property `ActionDescriptor`, which in turn has a `RouteValues` property. This should contain `officeId`.

Comment: @John do you have an example of using ActionDescriptor in this scenario?

Comment: I do not, but you could set a breakpoint and inspect its values at runtime to get an idea of how the data is structured.